# Form validation using javascript for password

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I would like for the form to give two error messages, one of "required" when the field is left blank, and another when the password is not enough characters in lenght, this is what I have, any help will be appreciated. I only get the "minimum characters"

```
  } else if ($element.hasClass('password-validator')) {
                        var message = $.validator.settings.messages.require;
                        len         = $element.prop('minlength') ? $element.prop('minlength') : 6;

                        if (!$.validator.isString($element.val(), len)) {
                            if (len >=5) {
                                message = 'The minimum password length is ' + len;
                            } else if (len == 0) {
                                message = 'Required';
                            }

                            $.validator.debug('validator():  error on password type for ' + $name);
                            $.validator.addErrorMessage($name, message);

                            $returnValue = false;
                            return true;
                        }
```

Comment: change your `(len >= 5)` to `(len <= 5)` ?

Comment: Also make sure you declare `len`, right now it's global.

Comment: Not sure why this is not working :(